# How do we test multiple scenarios for an API using postman?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

Using postman we can test individual API's and check its response which I am aware of.
However, now in order to test multiple scenarios for an API, are we supposed to create different API requests altogether or pass test data through JSON and run in multiple iterations?

If we run through multiple iterations, then how can we write 'Tests' for each API (POST/GET) request to check or compare against the test data passed?

Comment: There's a lot of things that you're asking but you haven't given an actual example of your implementation. Can you update your question and add more context.

Comment: Can you be little be specific about your question?